# how to use customization log4j in Flink job

Tags: log4j, apache-flink

we need to use different log4j.properties config in different flink job.
we use flink on yarn.
so how to use customization log4j in Flink job?
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use flink ClusterClient to submit tasks to yarn(Application Mode), you can set YarnConfigOptionsInternal.APPLICATION_LOG_CONFIG_FILE to address log4j configuration file.
e.g.

```
    // log file path
    flinkConfiguration.set(YarnConfigOptionsInternal.APPLICATION_LOG_CONFIG_FILE, flinkConfig.getLogFilePath());
    return flinkConfiguration;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer !! I will try it  ! We focus on the platform scenario, so we need a more general solution